# react native fbsdk linking error with FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to install **react-native-fbsdk** but I can't build the project, I get the following error:

> No visible @interface for 'FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction' declares the
>   selector 'initWithActionType:'

I added the xcode project inside my library and linked the file in link binary with libraries as well as places the fbsdk folder inside documents and added the path in framework search path.

I'm confused on which fbsdk file to download however, I'm not sure I have the right one.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I've just tried again multiples times in a lot of different ways until it worked, sorry for not being helpful.